# Set user selection to a getter - MIT App Inventor 2

Tags: java, app-inventor

I am trying to develop an app with MIT app inventor 2 and what I am trying to do at the moment is let the user select their country by a list picker and then take the user's selected country and save that to a getter so that another screen can access it and know what country the user chose in screen 1. 
Screen 1: Pick your country 
Screen 2: Pick your province 
So that based on the country they select, in screen 2 a list of provinces/states based on the country they selected in screen 1. 
Here's my code so far:

```
when countryListPicker.AfterPicking
do set countryListPicker.Text to CountryListPicker.Selection
```

I've tried many things for getters but keep getting errors.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my own question,
Youtube video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rm5VotkyuLs